# How to determine what command is run in a Nagios service?

Tags: nagios

I'm trying to debug why a Nagios service is failing; AFAIK, it began failing suddenly, without any change being made that we're aware of. I'm attempting to find a principled way to go from service to "command that this runs, that fails" so as to debug that.

The service is named "NTP"; in my `/etc/nagios3/conf.d`, I have,

```
define service {
    use                         service-passive-critical
    hostgroup_name              web-internal
    service_description         NTP
}
```

No `check_command`. Looking then at `serivce-passive-critical`,

```
define service {
    name                        service-passive-critical
    use                         service-passive
    notification_interval       1 ; always re-send alerts, PagerDuty will dedup
    contact_groups              contact-group-24x7
    freshness_threshold         900 ; treat service as stale if no updates for 15 min
    check_command               return-critical ; alert CRITICAL if service is stale
}
```

A `check_command`! But near as I can tell, that should always return CRITICAL, like the name suggests. My service is failing with UNKNOWN, and the message "can't create socket connection". The logs,

```
[1439835980] PASSIVE SERVICE CHECK: my-thing.example.com;NTP;3;can't create socket connection
```

For completeness, `service-passive`:

```
# passive services
define service {
    use                         foo-service
    name                        service-passive
    active_checks_enabled       0
    passive_checks_enabled      1
    parallelize_check           1
    obsess_over_service         0
    check_freshness             1
    freshness_threshold         900 ; treat service as stale if no updates for 15 min
    check_command               return-unknown ; alert UNKNOWN if service is stale
}
```

…

```
# for all our services we attach a graph link
define service {
    name                        foo-service
    use                         generic-service
    action_url                  /nagiosgraph/cgi-bin/show.cgi?host=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$
    register                    0
}
```

Now, my more common-sense guess is that this ends up running `check_ntp`; this *does* output the "can't create socket connection" error I see *depending on the arguments I pass it* (which is why it'd be so nice to know what Nagios is doing here…); I still have no idea why it started failing suddenly.

Also, is there a way to tell if this is being run locally, on the Nagios host itself, or remotely, through NRPE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *passive* service, right?  If you've not changed the config, then your NAGIOS was never running any command **at all** for this particular service - it was logging data being fed in from outside, via (eg) NSCA.

In fact, I suspect it still is: the external system is feeding in a hostname, a service, a status code (`3`), and an error message (`can't create socket connection`).

The use of a stub active command that returns e.g. `CRITICAL` is usual with such services, because it works alongside freshness checking to cause the serivce to go `CRITICAL` if no data is received from the outside sender for a certain period (here, 900s).  This prevents PASSIVE services from failing silently when the sender goes quiet, which is good practice.

Comment: It is indeed a passive service, and you're right: it's the host itself running the command & feeding the result to the server. (In my case, it's a cron job on the host that eventually calls `send_nsca`)

Comment: Glad to have pointed you in the right direction!